# Azure container registry: Image doesn't update when a publish through Visual Studio

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I configured Visual Studio to publish a docker image to Azure Container Registry and deploy it to an Azure App Service, the idea is: Every time I update my application, I'll publish the image to ACR and then, restart the App Service to update.

The problem is: the App Service container never updates, even the "latest" image doesn't look to update on ACR, the field "Tag last updated date" keeps the same, no matter how many times I publish the image from VS.

Actually, the only thing that modifies on ACR is the Pull Graphic count.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio only pushes the image if there is no other with the same tag on ACR.